# submit_tag without a button or image on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit

How do I create a submit action in form not by a button (with submit_tag) and not by an image (image_submit_tag)?

I'd like the submit to be clickable text like a link

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to do that with javascript, since links are a GET request, not a post request. So let's say you have the following code:

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => { :id => 'form' } do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <a id="submit">Submit</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You then need to add the following to one of your javascript files. If you're using < Rails 3.1, just simply add this to your application.js. If you're using Rails 3.1, add it to one of the js files in assets/javascripts directory.

```
$(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#form').submit();
  });
});
```

That said, you can pass the method option into a link_to method call, to use POST. However, just doing that without javascript will not submit any of the form data. So you would either have to do the above, or use javascript to add the data to the url like you would in a query string.

Comment: Thanks. If I add it to the application.js would it be applicable in all views, pages, etc?

Comment: My default, application.js is included in your layout file. If you have a look, check out the line: `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`, or something like that. The defaults symbol includes various js libraries, as well as application.js. If you aren't in Rails 3.1, you might need to add jQuery to your application for the above code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that I did it:

```
<a><%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "fake-button" %></a>
```

Then, change the styling:

```
.fake-button {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

So it's still technically a button but looks very much like a link. It's a bit hacky though :)